# How we can we disable the captcha after clicking submit button when the promise or work is resolved (the captcha should be disable)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am facing issue when the main body work of the function completed then the captcha remained open as same it is enabled on screen.
After process completion it should have to disable.

I have tried it on my running app but the captcha remained opened.

window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
'size': 'invisible',
'callback': (response) => {

}
});

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow @Sami Khan. Please add code so that we can give you the best possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey @sami khan hope this answer clear your problem;
just display none the captcha when your task is completed

```
function disableCaptcha() {
  const captchaElement = document.getElementById('captcha');
  captchaElement.style.display = 'none';
  captchaElement.innerHTML = '';
}
```